# Create HTML table from Google API external data (JSON) source from Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am attempting to create a basic table from an external data source from Google Analytics with jQuery. Below is the data format:

```
"rows": [
[
  "Provider283",
  "Email",
  "1"
],
[
  "Provider283",
  "Website",
  "4"
]
]
```

I am trying to create a table with rows from this with my own custom headers of Providers, Type and Count. The best I can seem to do is output rows of "Providers283, Email, 1" which isn't so nice to look at. How do I get each one of these comma delimited items to be in their own table column respectively using JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data stored in a variable, you can simply loop through this array and create a table-row.
For each array, you can also loop through and create a table-cell with the content.

See an example here:

```
var rows = [
  [
    'Provider',
    'E-Mail',
    '1'
  ],
  [
    'Provider',
    'Website',
    '4'
  ],
];

var html = '<table>';
for(var i = 0; i<rows.length; i++){
  html += '<tr>';
  for(var i2 = 0; i2<rows[i].length; i2++){
    html += '<td>' + rows[i][i2] + '</td>';
  }
  html += '<tr>';
}
html += '</table>';
      
document.write(html);
```

This will loop through the array `rows` and stores the HTML-Content in the variable `html`.
After the loop, it writes it to the document with `document.write`.